# A problem involving dense orbits of a continuous map

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, dynamical-systems

> > Let $T : X \to X$ be a continuous map of a metric space $X$ with no isolated points and let $p \in X$ and $\mathcal{O}^+(p) = \{T^n(p) : n =0, 1, 2 ...\}$ the positive orbit of $p$. Show that if $x$  is in the closure of the positive orbit of $p$, then $x$ is an accumulation point of $\mathcal{O}^+(p)$. Conclude that if $p$ has a positive dense orbit, then every point in the positive orbit of $p$ has a positive dense orbit.

I can't show the last part: if $p$ has a positive dense orbit, then every point in the positive orbit of $p$ has a positive dense orbit. Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially the same as saying that if any sequence $(p_0,p_1,...,p_n,...)$ is dense, then taking out a finite number of elements still leaves it a dense sequence $(p_n,p_{n+1},...)$.

If you have in any neighborhood of $x$ an infinite number of elements of the first sequence, you have still infinitely many elements of the second sequence in it.